# How to send the path of a target file using post method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<a href = 'view.php?path=...very long path' target='_blank'>PREVIEW</a>
```

Is it possible the same but using `$.post`, instead of `url`?

Something like this:

**index.js**

```
var lpath = 'home/lorem ipsum/lorem lorem/target.html';
$.post('../view.php', {path: lpath});
window.open('../view.php', '_blank');
```

**view.php**

```
$cnt = file_get_contents($_POST['path']);
echo $cnt;
```

**result on view.php:**

```
Undefined index path  
file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```

I hope you understand the idea:

- send the path of `target.html` to `view.php` using `$.post` method (or any suitable, but not via address bar
- on `view.php` get and echo the content of `target.html`

Any help?

Comment: post here is an ajax call, separate to your window open call. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @tim, this is a blog and the standatd method is - `view.php?id=5`. I want the same but without variables on address bar, - there is no database, just file system, all articles are inside files

Comment: what about using a session to hold the variable?

Comment: @tim but how to send the variable from `index.js` - there is a click event here - to `vew.php` using session?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("view.php",
  {
    imgPath: $("img").attr("href");
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

Maybe you can try something like this

Comment: no, I need the variable inside another file `view.php`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.post(`../view.php?path=${lpath}`);
```

in php use

```
$cnt = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['path']);
echo $cnt;
```